# Create class instance variables using a locals()['some_string'] like approach

Tags: python, string, class, variables, concatenation

Sometimes I need to create new variables with a suffix using a variable, which I can with something like:

```
Number=5
locals()['First'+str(Number)]=5
```

Resulting in the variable *First5* which is = 5.

How can I do the same thing in a class instance?

```
class foo:
    def appender(self,bar):
        for i in range(bar):
            self.locals()['Number'+str(i)]=i
#-----
qq=foo()
qq.appender(3) #issues...
```

I would like this to create qq.Number0, qq.Number1 and qq.Number2, but it tells me that foo has no instance of locals.  How can I concatenate strings to create new variables in my instance?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `foo.__dict__`, or `self.__dict__`?

Comment: I think I am looking for self.__dict__, as I only want it associated with the instance. Each instance may have a different number of 'bar', but maybe I'm just confused...

Comment: I think I get it. You want to dynamically set an attribute of a class so that the name is also created from the value, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically set attributes of a class instance you can use the internal method `__setattr__`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def appender(self, bar):
        self.__setattr__('Number' + str(bar), bar)
```

Which should give you:

```
>>>> foo = Foo()
>>>> foo.appender(1)
>>>> foo.Number1
1
```

Comment: Thank you MrAlias - I think this is the right path, although Python tells me thatfoo has no attribute '__setattr__'.

Comment: the underscores are important: `setattr != __setattr__`

Comment: Also make sure that you using the _new_ class style in python2 (i.e. `class foo(object):`)

Comment: That is it! I was creating my class with foo() and not foo(object). Now the settattr is there. THANK YOU!

Comment: yes this indeed looks like you are using the [old class type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).